# For some reason I get an error message when I try to run my balance command in discord.py whilst having the .json code in my number game

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I just started using .json a while back, to make an economy bot using discord.py. In my code I have a number guessing game which is pretty self explanatory, and when I play the game, everything goes well, but when I try to check my balance, I get this error:

```
line 59, in numguess
    guess = int(response.content)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'game.balance'
```

This is my actual code:

```
@bot.command()
async def numguess(ctx):
    global numguess_earnings

    await open_account(ctx.author)

    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()

    #main--------------------
    number = random.randint(0, 100)
    await ctx.send("I am thinking of a number from 1-100. What is it?")

    for i in range(0, 100):
        response = await ctx.bot.wait_for('message')

        guess = int(response.content)

        if guess > number:
            await ctx.send('That guess is too big! Try again!')

        elif guess < number:
            await ctx.send('That guess is too small! Try again!')

        else:
            await ctx.send(f'You got it right! It only took you {i + 1} attempts! {100 - (i+1)} coins have been earned!')

            numguess_earnings = 100 - (i + 1)
    #endmain-------------------

    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += numguess_earnings

    with open("main.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)



#ECONOMY COMMANDS===============================================================================================================================================
#balance-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@bot.command()
async def balance(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()

    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]

    em = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance", color = discord.Color.red())
    em.add_field(name = "Wallet balance", value = wallet_amt)


    await ctx.send(embed = em)


#helper commands---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#open account-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
async def open_account(user):

    users = await get_bank_data()

    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0


    with open("main.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
    return True

#get bank data-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
async def get_bank_data():
    with open("main.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    return users
```

I would also like to note that the command worked perfectly when I had both of the commands separated, but once I started to use the economy commands in the number games, the errors started to occur. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The bot has received a message with content `game.balance` which can not be converted into an integer. Make sure you type a number.

Moreover, use a check to only accept the message whose author is ctx.author and whose channel is ctx.channel and the content is a digit.

```py
def check(m):
    return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel and m.content.isdigit()
response = await ctx.bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
guess = int(response.content)
```